# What's the difference between an App and an AppPart?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app

I'm trying to understand the difference between an App and an App Part.
Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**App Part**
A component of an app for SharePoint that can be embedded on a site page to expose the functionality of the app.With app parts, you can show your app user experience (UX) right in the host web. An app part displays your app content using an IFrame. End users can customize the experience using the custom properties that you can provide for your app part.

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Creating-an-App-Part-and-Displaying-an-App-inside-the-App-Part-in-SharePoint-2013

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

**App**
A cloud-enabled app that integrates rich, scenario-focused content and services into a SharePoint environment.

Read this blog for more details:

http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=266
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/an-overview-of-sharepoint-2013-app-development-model/

http://blog.tahoepartners.com/index.php/sharepoint-2013-apps-six-reasons-you-should-care/

Comment: Your answer explained much better than mine.

Comment: Also in app part you cannot write .Net CSOM code.

Comment: I thought you could in Provider-hosted apps (and the now dead auto-hosted apps)